# ASP.NET, IIS 6 and url rewriting

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, url-rewriting

i've bought a shared hosting on a windows hoster with IIS 6.

I would like to know how to rewrite url.

I can't modify anything on the server, the only thing i can do is to use ... my asp.net code !
some advice ?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: thanks, but i've already look at that post and but i can't find a  solutions for iis 6 ! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the ScottGu blog suggests, you can

**1. Do the rewrite manually using the `HttpContext.RewritePath()` method that ASP.NET provides**

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    string fullOrigionalpath = Request.Url.ToString();

    if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Products/Books.aspx")) {
        Context.RewritePath("/Products.aspx?Category=Books");
    }
    else if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Products/DVDs.aspx")) {
        Context.RewritePath("/Products.aspx?Category=DVDs");
    }
}
```

**2. Use a HttpModule**
Using a `HttpModule` (such as [urlrewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net/)) does not require any changes on the server, only some changes on `Web.Config` and deploying the module DLLs