# URL rewriting in, IIS 6, .aspx

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-6

I've developed a small website in VS2012 that utilizes the following rewrite in `web.config`:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="DynamicRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

This works beautifully in IIS Express on my dev machine, but the server is running IIS 6, and the rewrite fails (I get 404 on URLs that should have worked).

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714974/asp-net-iis-6-and-url-rewriting), but it talks about `.asax` files, i.e. a web application. I only have a simple website with `Default.aspx` and some custom classes.

Is there any way for me to make this work? Basically, I want to be able to do it in `web.config` or my aspx-file, but I have full access to IIS so I can configure there as well, if that's what it takes (although I don't know how -- IIS 6 is really scary).

Currently, I'm on .NET 4.0 but I can always lower to 3.5 if needed (heard there were some rewriting-issues on extensionless URLs with 4.0, but I never really got the gist of it).